# MongoDB query to break ties and remove duplicates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents which have a Version, URL, and  DateAdded field (among others but these are the relevant ones).

I'd like to find all documents where the Version is "5.5" and the DateAdded is less than or equal to January 1, 2013. That's pretty straightforward, but I also want the following behavior:

If two or more documents have the same URL, only return the one with the most recent DateAdded (provided, again, that is is less than or equal to January 1, 2013). It would be great if all of this could be expressed in a single query (but my main concern is performance).

I've been doing this last bit of filtering in my client code (outside of MongoDB) but this ends up being inefficient, not to mention inelegant.

I've also tried using Mongo's MapReduce functionality to accomplish the same thing but this is extremely slow, as it appears to copy much of my collection to another collection.

Is there a performant solution?

Comment: Look at `aggregate` instead of `mapReduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

Example data:

```js
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("528bd5bded29286a62959513"), "Version" : "5.3", "URL" : "foo.bar.com/asdfwoaef", "DateAdded" : ISODate("2012-10-05T00:00:00Z") })
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("528bd5e8ed29286a62959514"), "Version" : "5.6", "URL" : "foo.bar.com/asdfwoaef", "DateAdded" : ISODate("2012-12-05T00:00:00Z") })
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("528bd621ed29286a62959515"), "Version" : "5.5", "URL" : "foo.bar.com/aafoobbb", "DateAdded" : ISODate("2012-11-04T00:00:00Z") })
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("528bd629ed29286a62959516"), "Version" : "5.5", "URL" : "foo.bar.com/aafoobbb", "DateAdded" : ISODate("2012-11-05T00:00:00Z") })
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("528bd642ed29286a62959517"), "Version" : "5.5", "URL" : "foo.bar.com/aafoobbb", "DateAdded" : ISODate("2013-01-02T00:00:00Z") })
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("528bd744ed29286a62959518"), "Version" : "5.5", "URL" : "foo.bar.com/ccbarcc", "DateAdded" : ISODate("2013-01-02T00:00:00Z") })
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("528bd780ed29286a62959519"), "Version" : "5.5", "URL" : "foo.bar.com/ccbarcc", "DateAdded" : ISODate("2012-04-05T00:00:00Z") })
```

Pipeline:

```js
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match" : {
            "Version" : "5.5",
            "DateAdded" : {
                "$lt" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "URL" : 1,
            "DateAdded" : -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$URL",
            "doc" : {
                "$first" : {
                    "id" : "$_id",
                    "DateAdded" : "$DateAdded"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

db.foo.aggregate(pipeline)
```

And here is the result:

```js
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "foo.bar.com/ccbarcc",
            "doc" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("528bd780ed29286a62959519"),
                "DateAdded" : ISODate("2012-04-05T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : "foo.bar.com/aafoobbb",
            "doc" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("528bd629ed29286a62959516"),
                "DateAdded" : ISODate("2012-11-05T00:00:00Z")
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. It returns:
    { "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }

Comment: I've posted an update with example data. Can you check it? My guess is for some reason you miss all the data in the `$match` phase.

Comment: This works! Now I'll tweak it to work with my actual data...I was bad and I tried to simplify my actual field names in this post. So that's my problem. One question...is it possible to get the pipeline to strip off the outer "result" object so that what is returned is an array or cursor similar to what is returned by db.collection.find()? That way I would not have to change the code that processes query results. Thanks!

Comment: Other than `db.foo.aggregate(pipeline).result`? Not really unless you want to use development version.

Comment: OK, one last question. I want the results to contain all fields (or maybe a subset of fields that I specify, similar to the projection argument of db.collection.find(), and I'd rather not hardcode "field1": "$field1", "field2": "$field2" into the pipeline. Any ideas? I'm particularly interested in the case where I want all fields to be returned in the result (without knowing beforehand what 'all fields' are).

Comment: As far as I know there is no simple built-in solution when you use `$group` phase. You have to remember that in a MongoDB 2.4 aggregation result is a single document and it cannot be bigger than 16MB. One way of solving the problem would be to perform full scan of the collection and extract names of the top level fiels to create projection argument for the `$group`.